# Generic classes in my application

Tags: java, oop

I've created a few minor apps for Android while learning. Being a PHP developer, it's a challenge to get used to it.

I'm especially wondering how I could define a couple of "general" functions in a separate class. Eg I have a function that checks if network connection is available, and if not, shows a dialog saying that the user should enable it. Currently, that function exists in several of my activities. Of course that seems strange - I suppose it would be more logical to define it once and include it in the activites where needed.

I tried putting it in a new class, and included that class in the original activity. But that failed since eg getBaseContext() is not accepted anymore.

I'm wondering how to go ahead. What should I be Google-ing for ? What is this mechanism called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create class with static methods. Like this

```
public class HelperUtils {
     public static void checkNetworkConnection(Context ctx) {...}
}
```

Then you can call it from any place like this:

```
HelperUtils.checkNetworkConnection(this.getContext());
```

Assuming current class has Context.

You should read books on general OOP concepts where different type of methods are explained.

Comment: thanks! I'm aware of the OOP concepts and how to handle them in PHP, but I have to get used to them in java... a lot of work ahead :)

Answer (score 1):

You can for example create a class - let's call it NetworkUtils. In this class you can create static method boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable() and return true if is available and false  otherwise. In this class you can create another static method void showNoConnectionDialog(Activity activity) - and in this method you create dialog starting with

```
public static void showNoConnectionDialog(Activity activity) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //setting message, listener etc. and finally
    builder.create().show();
}
```

In your activity, where you want to check and handle network connection you should call:

```
if (!NetworkUtils.isConnectionAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
    NetworkUtils.showNoConnectionDialog(YourActivityClassName.this)
}
```

I guess this should work.